# Prediction is depending on the batch size in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to use keras for binary classification of an image.

My CNN model is well trained on the training data (giving ~90% training accuracy and ~93% validation accuracy). But during training if I set the batch size=15000 I get the Figure I output and if I set the batch size=50000 I get Figure II as the output. Can someone please tell what is wrong? The prediction should not depend on batch size right?

Code I am using for prediction :

`y=model.predict_classes(patches, batch_size=50000,verbose=1)
 y=y.reshape((256,256))`

[image: Figure 1] [image: Figure 2]

My model:-

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                        input_shape=(img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# let's train the model using SGD + momentum (how original).
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: actually it seems that the prediction size is important and affect the result. check the kares code:
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py [line 818]
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/models.py
[line 548]

Comment: So, any solution? :(

Comment: The solution is the same as always for neural networks: Try different settings and compare. See also [http://svail.github.io/rnn_perf/](http://svail.github.io/rnn_perf/), section 5.1

Comment: Exactly! try to find a suitable value for batch size, you can also try the default value which is 32

Comment: For training, I can understand that batch size has some effect on accuracy. But the prediction should be dependent on the batch size?

Comment: for the last question, do you have found an answer why there is a batch size in `predict_classes`?

Comment: Nopes. Moved to Lasagne and its working fine for me :)

Answer (score 7):

Keras is standarizing input automaticaly in the `predict` function. The statistics needed for standarization are computed on a batch - that's why your outputs might depend on a batch size. You may solve this by :

1. If Keras > 1.0 you could simply define your model in functional API and simpy apply a trained function to self standarized data.
2. If you have your model trained - you could recover it as Theano function and also apply it to self standarized data.
3. If your data is not very big you could also simply set your batch size to the number of examples in your dataset.

**UPDATE:** here is a code for 2nd solution :

```
import theano

input = model.layers[0].input # Gets input Theano tensor
output = model.layers[-1].output # Gets output Theano tensor
model_theano = theano.function(input, output) # Compiling theano function 

# Now model_theano is a function which behaves exactly like your classifier 

predicted_score = model_theano(example) # returns predicted_score for an example argument
```

Now if you want to use this new `theano_model` you should standarize main dataset on your own (e.g. by subtracting mean and dividing by standard deviation every pixel in your image) and apply `theano_model` to obtain scores for a whole dataset (you could do this in a loop iterating over examples or using `numpy.apply_along_axis` or `numpy.apply_over_axes` functions).

**UPDATE 2:** in order to make this solution working change

```
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

to:

```
model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation = "softmax"))
```

Comment: First of all my dataset is too big to fit in the GPU. Can you please tell me more about the 2nd point.?

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I am just a beginner. Can you please comment the code so that I can understand what's going on? can I send the patches in batch mode?

Comment: 'AttributeError: 'Activation' object has no attribute 'output'' - getting this error. Any pointer?

Comment: Please post your code with model defined - it would be easier :)

Comment: Added in my question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112953/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-avijit-dasgupta).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I think it's connected to the GPU's non-determinism - on the CPU the results were identical, on the GPU (RTX 2080Ti and RTX 3090) they were not. I couldn't solve it (using deterministic options for GPU didn't work).