# How does the batch size affect the quality of the predict/predict_on_batch method in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

On my way on enhancing the speed of my LSTM-NN I stumbled upon a question.

How does the batch size affect the quality of the predict/predict_on_batch method?

To specify: I know it does affect the calculation of the gradient in training phase and therefore the prediction results,
but should the prediction result vary if different batch sizes are used for batch prediction
(with same size of training batch size)?
Or should one always use the same batch size for training/fitting and prediction, and if so why?

What I tried:

I have a well working (0.96 detection rate and 0 false alarms) LSTM for anomaly detection
but it takes a long time to go through all test files because of the slow prediction (40min),
using predict(x) trained with a batch_size of 512.
When using predict_on_batch with batch_size=1 it again takes 35 min to test with 0.96 DR and 0 FA.

When using predict_on_batch(batch, batch_size), same with predict(batch, batch_size),
with batch size 512 (same as used in training) instead of predict(x) it takes only ca.32sec
but the results are way worse (0.63 DR, 62455 FA).
Similar applies to smaller batch_size values greater than 1.

The answer  in this thread: [Prediction is depending on the batch size in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429728/prediction-is-depending-on-the-batch-size-in-keras) is pretty outdated but is it still accurate (blaming standardization)?

I dont really understand what is happening here, hope someone can clearify!

Versions used:

```
Keras 2.3.1
Python 3.7.4
```

Comment: Take a look at similar issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33104.

Comment: Check https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/does-batch-size-in-keras-have-any-effects-in-results-quality